# Append specific string to the start of each line of an output file while streaming result of a command to the same file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

Not too certain how to word this. I am trying to write a shell command that will append the first part of a file name to the beginning of each line while streaming the result of a command, in a for loop, that will create the lines in the file. At the same time, I am removing certain lines in the stream that I do not want to write in the file. For example, I have 4 files which are pairs, essentially 2 pair of files.

```
file1.a.txt
1
2

file1.b.txt 
a
b
c

file2.a.txt
3
8
4

file2.b.txt
d
c
c
a
```

when I run the shell command, I expect to get just one file with first part of file name and whatever the output of my script command is. The script command will always generate a result with number of lines equal to the number of lines in b.txt and certain lines that I do not have a need for
Expected result:

result.txt

```
file1 script result for line containing a in file1.b.txt
file1 script result for line containing b in file1.b.txt
file1 script result for line containing c in file1.b.txt
file2 script result for line containing d in file2.b.txt
file2 script result for line containing c in file2.b.txt
file2 script result for line containing c in file2.b.txt
file2 script result for line containing a in file2.b.txt
```

What I have so far:

```
for x in *a.txt; do echo $(x%.*.*};script command result | sed '/^\(/d'| sed '/^0/d' >> result.txt
```

This is generating the result.txt with correct lines but the name I am trying to append to the start of each line is missing from the start of each line. That is, it is getting printed to the screen, I believe due to echo. I need help getting to my desired result.

Comment: what does "script command result from stdin" mean, you have to be passing the file names to the script.  Note that if you're piping in the data from stdin, the filename info will be lost.

Comment: the script I run takes the files, processes them and writes the result to screen. Rather than having it on screen I just pipe it through the sed commands so as to filter out some lines that I don't need before appending to the results file.

Comment: The question is how it takes the files?  Are you calling the script `script file.a file.b?`  What you do with the output is not important.

Comment: So you are trying to write `sed "s/^/$filename/"`? What does `script command result` outputs by itself and how is it related to presented `result.txt` content?

Comment: Yes I call a pair of files with the script and then process the next pairs etc. I ensure the pairs match. Also, yes @KamilCuk but I have tried that too. It just will not append to the lines as they are being written

Comment: @KamilCuk its just like using cat command. cat file1 and cat file2 but you want the streamed lines from the cat command to another file while at the same time appending the name of the file been processed to each line spewed by the cat command

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* you want:

```
for x in *a.txt; do
   script command result | 
   sed '/^\(/d'| sed '/^0/d' |
   sed "s/^/$x/" >> result.txt
done
```